# How to execute a function from RAM memory on STM32 QEMU debugger eclipse in C?

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded, stm32, qemu

I'am using the STM32 QEMU debugger to test the code. I'm erase the while(1) because I just test the function.

```
typedef int(*fnc_t) (int);

int multiply(int data) {
    return (data * 5);
}

void memorycopy( unsigned char *src, unsigned char *dst, int size ) {
    int j;
    for( j=0; j < size; j++ ) {
        dst[j] = src[j];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    unsigned int ram_vector[6];
    fnc_t fnc_ram;

    printf("1\n");
    fnc_ram = (fnc_t) ( (int) &ram_vector + 1);
    printf("2\n");

    volatile int z = (int)( &multiply - 1);

    memorycopy( (unsigned char*) z, (unsigned char*) fnc_ram, 6);

    printf("3\n");
    i = fnc_ram(3);
    printf("4\n");
    printf("Novo i: %d\n",i);
    printf("5\n");
}
```

But when I call the function i = fnc_ram(3); the follow error occurs:
[image]

Comment: Why `&ram_vector + 1` and why `&multiply - 1`  why not just ram_vector and multiply?

Comment: because the processor is ARM

Comment: arm does not require a + 1, that is a bug in a number of ways, orred with 1, sure for safety but that just means you are using the tools incorrectly.  the cortex-ms have a vector table not an entry point you just start executing, if you want to run in ram and not use the address 0x00000000 vector table then use a different bootstrap for ram...copy from rom and jump.

Comment: what is your qemu line?  what machine/target are you using in qemu?  and where is this ram you want to execute a program in?

Comment: STM32F407VG, I don't know where are the RAM, I think that is in the MCU.

Comment: I dont see anything stm32 in qemu.  How is qemu related to this?  Are you running on real hardware?

Comment: yeah the + 1 is definitely a problem for starters, you are misunderstanding things by doing that, what does your disassembly show related to that line of code?

Comment: what "function" are you trying to copy to ram?

Comment: https://ibb.co/m6Gvya, this is what I see.

Comment: you have an stm32f4 discovery board, what does qemu have to do with this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153815/discussion-between-augusto-and-old-timer).

Comment: why you delete your post? He was complete and very good.

Answer (score 0):

You're not copying enough bytes.  Your memorycopy function only copys 6 bytes and you want 6 integers don't you?

Comment: The size I check on memory map generated by debug

Comment: When I tested this on my x86 I got rid of the +1 -1 and copy 4*size bytes and it works.

Comment: I rid +1 and -1, and change size do 24. Keeping not working